# retrieve dynamic ID of textbox in asp.net

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a control that creates textboxes dynamically.

For each of these textboxes I want to make an insert to my SQL database.

For example I have 3 textboxes with id `FlottenID1`, `FlottenID2`, `FlottenID3`.

Every TextBox has default of `FlottenID` and then comes the number 1,2,3,4,5 depending on how many I have.

Now I need help how can I say in my insert Loop that it should start with inserting `FlottenID1` and then next time it will be `FlottenID2` and so on...

My other id's always have the same Name so there it is no problem. There I can only write `Cust.text` for example. Hope you understand what I'm searching for. Thanks!

```
protected void btnGenerateControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int Count = Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text);

        for(int i =1; i <= Count; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            lbl.Text = " Flotten ID Velo Nr" + (i).ToString() + " ";
            //txtbox.Text = "Textbox - " + i.ToString();
            txtbox.ID = "FlottenID" + i.ToString();
            txtbox.EnableViewState = true;
            pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(lbl);
            pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txtbox);
            pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));
        }
    }

protected void btnAddOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int Count = Convert.ToInt32(Qty.Text);
        for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
        {

            String query = "insert into Orders (CustID, OrderDate, Time, ProductID, ProjectID, Status, FlottenID)values('" + CustID.Text + "','" + OrderDate.Text + "','" + Time.Text + "','" + ProductID.Value + "','" + ProjectID.Value + "','" + Status.Value + "','" + " FlottenID " + "')";
            String query1 = "commit;";
            DataLayer.DataConnector dat = new DataLayer.DataConnector("Provider=SQLOLEDB; data source=****;database=***;user ID=event;password=****; Persist Security Info=False");
            dat.DataInsert(query);
            dat.DataInsert(query1);
      }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked same question which i gave the solution to that.Anyway I give the code now..

Write the below code in btnGenerateControl_Click1 Event(below For Loop)

```
 pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input id='txtbox' name='FlottenID" + i + "'type='text'  />"));
        pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

This generates TextBox ids Like (FlottenID1,FlottenID2,..........Based on the For Loop)